# How to add mark over a image box?

Tags: c#

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.imgRoom.Click += new EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label1 = new LabelControl();
    label1.Location = MousePosition;
    label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    label1.Parent = imgRoom;
    label1.Text = "Point";
    imgRoom.Controls.Add(label1);
}
```

[image]

When I click in place, which you can see on the attached screen, point appear in another place. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MousePosition` is in screen coordinates.  You need to convert it to client coordinates.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var label1 = new LabelControl();
        label1.Location = imgRoom.PointToClient(MousePosition);  // changed here.
        label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label1.Parent = imgRoom;
        label1.Text = "Point";
        imgRoom.Controls.Add(label1);
    }
```

Comment: Great. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to the mouse position relative to the form not the picture box. Try using the pictureBox 'mouseClick' event and then using the mouseEventArgs 'e.Location' property to set your label's Location property.

see - (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx)